# How to make <html:select> tag REQUIRED

Tags: html, struts-1, taglib

In HTML the select tag has the *required* attribute that "Specifies that the user is required to select a value before submitting the form". [read here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

In Struts 1 the "html:select" tag doesn't have the attribute "*required*": [read here](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/select.html)

How can I specify that the user is required to select a value before submitting the form in Struts 1 for the select box?

```
<td class="insdataheader">
    <label for="initReqList[0].seqType">
         <bean:message bundle="XYZ" key="it.myproject.cbi2.disposals.v000104.model.MndtInitiationRequestV02.seqType"/>
    </label>
</td>

<td class="insdatitxt_inserita_nowrap" align="left">
    <html:select property="initReqList[0].seqType" name="initReqList[0].seqType" styleId="initReqList[0].seqType" value="${dataEntryForm.initReqList[0].seqType}">
          <html-ext:keyOptionsCollection bundle="XYZ" name="dataEntryForm" property="initReqList[0].seqTypeOptions" label="keyBundle"value="key"  
   </html:select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this,javascript

**JQuery**

```
 $(function(){
            var elem = document.getElementsByName('initReqList[0].seqType')[0];
            jQuery(elem).attr('required','required');
        });
```

if need this in htmt tld than you have to edit html tld and have to add custom code to it and respective java class

Comment: Great! I have another problem, is there a way to make the label RED? If I try putting <label class="mandatoryLabel"> it works but in this way <label for="initReqList[0].seqType" class="mandatoryLabel"> it doesn't work.I think that for some reason the "for" conflicts with the "class" attribute...

Comment: it is not conflict something other class is overiding it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `required` property in the `<html:select />` tag and you must have an empty option.

Example:

```
<html:select required="required" property="initReqList[0].seqType" name="initReqList[0].seqType" styleId="initReqList[0].seqType" value="${dataEntryForm.initReqList[0].seqType}">
    <html-ext:keyOptionsCollection bundle="XYZ" name="dataEntryForm" property="initReqList[0].seqTypeOptions" label="keyBundle"value="key"  
</html:select>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried again BUT the required="required" is not accepted in the html:select http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/select.html

Comment: Adding required="required" to a struts radio button selector worked really well.  So surprised it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - Have the first value empty - required works on empty values.

```
<select required>
 <option value="">Please select</option>
 <option value="one">One</option>
 <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the user will be required to select a value before submitting the form.

Comment: Yes, in normal html it works, but how can I do that in struts with html:select tag?